# Currying with Haskell with functor and function composition

Tags: haskell, currying

I have following problem. I have a function that works nice.

```
getName :: Style -> Css -> Maybe String
getName s css = map intToChar .  intToBase 26 <$> getIndex s css
```

I wonder why I can't define it that way:

```
getName :: Style -> Css -> Maybe String
getName = map intToChar .  intToBase 26 <$> getIndex
```

I thought currying would allow me to return that as function that will take two parameters instead of being a function that have two parameters

If it helps your for understanding:

```
intToChar :: Int -> Char
intToBase :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
getIndex :: Style > Css -> Maybe Int
```

Ahh don't forget the error:

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[a] -> Maybe Int’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: a -> Int
        Actual type: a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
    • Probable cause: ‘getIndex’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘getIndex’
      In the expression: map intToChar . intToBase 26 <$> getIndex
      In an equation for ‘getName’:
          getName = map intToChar . intToBase 26 <$> getIndex
    • Relevant bindings include
        getName :: a -> [Char] (bound at src/Css/Css.hs:17:1)
   |        
17 | getName = map intToChar .  intToBase 26 <$> getIndex 
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's eta-reduce one argument. This requires transforming the operator into a section

```
getName s css = map intToChar . intToBase 26 <$> getIndex s css

getName s = (map intToChar . intToBase 26 <$>) . getIndex s
```

aka

```
getName s = fmap (map intToChar . intToBase 26) . getIndex s
```

Now, it is possible to see function post-composition as another functor operation<sup>†</sup>, but it would need to be mentioned explicitly:

```
getName s = fmap (fmap (map intToChar . intToBase 26)) (getIndex s)
```

This is awkward. Some libraries define operators like [`<<$>>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/protolude-0.3.0/docs/Protolude.html#v:-60--60--36--62--62-) that allow compacting this to

```
getName s = map intToChar . intToBase 26 <<$>> getIndex s
```

but this doesn't really scale well – you'd need a different operator for every depth of nesting. Though, we could certainly define it ourselves:

```
infixl 4 <<<$>>>
(<<<$>>>) :: (Functor f, Functor g, Functor h)
            => (a->b) -> f (g (h a)) -> f (g (h b))
(<<<$>>>) = fmap . fmap . fmap

getName = map intToChar . intToBase 26 <<<$>>> getIndex
```

Alternatively you could merge, i.e. [compose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) the different functors into a single one:

```
getName s = getCompose $ map intToChar . intToBase 26 <$> Compose (getIndex s)
```

...which kind-of scales also to including the other argument

```
getName = getCompose . getCompose $ map intToChar . intToBase 26 <$> Compose (Compose getIndex)
```

but that's obviously no win at all over any of the previous forms. The same thing could also be expressed with the [`ReaderT` monad transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t:ReaderT), but that gets just as unreadable. Likewise for various point-free escapades involving partially applied composition operators.

**tl;dr** it's not worth it, just keep the arguments as you had them originally.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>I'm *generally* not a fan of the `(c->)` functor. Haskell has enough functors floating around, but it has excellent special syntax for plain old functions, so why not just use it and keep it clear what functor is just a function composition.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `s` and `css` cannot be eliminated via [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion), because they are used as arguments to `getIndex` alone, not `map intToChar . intToBase 26 <$> getIndex`.

To go point-free, you have to use function composition. To start, rewrite your definition using `fmap` instead of `<$>` (and hiding the irrelevant argument to `fmap` behind a local variable).

```
getName s css = fmap f (getIndex s css)
    where f = map intToChar . intToBase 26
```

Now it's easier to see that you need to use function composition to first eliminate `css`:

```
-- f1 (f2 x) == f1 . f2
-- f1 = fmap f
-- f2 = getIndex s
getName s = fmap f . (getIndex s)
    where f = map intToChar . intToBase 26
```

and then `s`:

```
-- f1 (f2 x) = f1 . f2
-- f1 = (fmap f .)
-- f2 = getIndex
getName = (fmap f . ) . getIndex
    where f = map intToChar . intToBase 26
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps some parenthesization is in order. First, the principle you're trying to apply is valid. Namely, if a variable is the final argument to your function and is the final argument to the top-level call in your function, you can effectively "right-cancel" the two variables, so if you had

```
prependMy x = mappend "my" x
```

Then you could safely "cancel" the `x` and get the equivalent (modulo monomorphism restriction, which doesn't apply here but can bite you sometimes)

```
prependMy = mappend "my"
```

Now, this is your expression.

```
getName s css = map intToChar .  intToBase 26 <$> getIndex s css
```

Now the same thing with some parentheses for clarity

```
getName s css = (map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$> (getIndex s css)
```

Now the `css` isn't on the top-level anymore. It wasn't before, but it's more clear now that it's not. If you can rearrange the expression so that `s` and `css` are actually at the top-level call, then you can still cancel off. In this case, you could get rid of `css` by doing something like this.

```
getName s css = (map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$> (getIndex s css)
getName s css = ((map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$>) (getIndex s css)
getName s css = (((map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$>) . getIndex s) css
getName s = ((map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$>) . getIndex s
```

Then you can get rid of `s` by following the same logic

```
getName s = ((map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$>) . (getIndex s)
getName s = (((map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$>) .) (getIndex s)
getName s = ((((map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$>) .) . getIndex) s
getName = (((map intToChar .  intToBase 26) <$>) .) . getIndex
```

But that's not really more readable than the original. Removing the arguments like this is called [pointfreeing](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) a function. It *can* be done to basically any function, but it should be done sparingly, as you can easily end up with something incomprehensible.